# Remove down arrow from folders in personal toolbar in Firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, gnome

In Linux version of firefox (specifically in my case Debian's rebranded Iceweasel), folders of bookmarks in the personal toolbar show a little down arrow on the right of the name. It serves no real purpose and just takes up horizontal space, is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put below code in ~/.mozilla/firefox/XXXX.default/chrome/userChrome.css

```
/*Hide Bookmark Folder Icon*/
#bookmarksBarContent toolbarbutton[type=menu] image {
display: none !important;
-moz-margin-end: 0px !important;
}
#bookmarksBarContent toolbarbutton[container="true"] .toolbarbutton-menu-dropmarker {
display: none !important;
}
```

reference: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/760156

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the correct code is :

```
/*Hide Bookmark Folder Icon*/
/*#personal-bookmarks toolbarbutton[type=menu] image {
display: none !important;
-moz-margin-end: 0px !important;
}*/
#personal-bookmarks toolbarbutton[container="true"] .toolbarbutton-menu-dropmarker {
display: none !important;
}
```

in FF 9.01, Ubuntu 11.10 - and I think this still leaves extra free space